# PHP file -bi or FileInfo

Tags: php, linux, unix, command-line, fileinfo

I'm creating a Joomla Upload Component and a mime-type check is quite necessary as you well know.

I'd really like to enable mime-type checking for everyone, but unfortunately not everyone uses PHP 5.3+ and not everyone can enable FileInfo on their servers.

So my question is so, how reliable is file - bi 'filename.ext' compared to FileInfo?
Which should be used first and which as a fallback?

P.S. I do know that file command is only available for *nix servers.